# PHPMyAdmin HTTPS Configuration with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, ssl, https, phpmyadmin

I'm new to Docker and I'm encountering difficulties configuring PHPMyAdmin with Docker Compose to work with HTTPS on localhost on port `8443`. I've managed to set up PHPMyAdmin with Docker Compose and make it accessible via HTTP on port `8080`. However, I also want to replicate the production environment using HTTPS. In the end, I need a MySQL container on port `3306` SSL linked to a PHPMyAdmin container on port `8443` and a Prestashop container on port `8000`.

I checked my SSL configuration in the `config.user.inc.php` file and in the PHPMyAdmin container configuration, but I couldn't resolve the issue. I also came across suggestions indicating that SSL certificates need to be generated, but I haven't found specific resources on generating certificates for localhost in a Docker environment.

Here are my current files:

`.env`

```
HTTP_PORT=80
SSL_PORT=443

DB_SERVER=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_NAME=3maj
DB_USER=3maj
DB_PASSWORD=password

PMA_PORT=8080
PMA_SSL_PORT=8443
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.9"
networks:
  3maj:
volumes:
  dbdata:
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: 3maj-mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - 3maj
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'no'
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: 3maj-phpmyadmin
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - 3maj
    links:
      - mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - ${PMA_PORT}:443
      - ${PMA_SSL_PORT}:80
    volumes:
      - ./config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: ${DB_SERVER}
      PMA_USER: ${DB_USER}
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
```

`config.user.inc.php`

```php
<?php

$i = 1;
$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_verify'] = true;
```

Can someone please tell me how to make it work?